# Why are (co)homology groups algebraic invariants?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, invariance, mayer-vietoris-sequence

Background & definitions:
I am studying algebraic topology, in particular (co)homology groups and Mayer-Vietoris sequences.

Important terms:

**Algebraic invariant** = property of a topo. space preserved under algebraic transformations (e.g. transformation given by a general linear group).

**Mayer-Vietoris-sequence** in this context, I work with the sequence for reduced homology groups (which is a bit nicer). [image]

From the intro of [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence):

> In mathematics, particularly algebraic topology and homology theory, the Mayer–Vietoris sequence is an algebraic tool to help compute **algebraic invariants** of topological spaces, **known as their homology and cohomology groups**.

**My question:**
How are (co)homology groups **algebraic** invariants? Why not **topological** invariants instead?
I want to know what properties of a topo. space *X* (co)homology groups preserve.

I am gratfeul for any insgiths, also possibly from category-theoretic view ((co)homology as functors etc.)

Comment: I think your definition of an *algebraic invariant* is strange. In the set up of Mayer-Vietoris the general linear group is usually not acting on any of the spaces $A$ or $B$. I may be wrong but I would guess that in this context an *algebraic invariant of a topological space* is an object in some algebraic category that is immune to homeomorphisms. Basically a functor from a topological category to an algebraic one.

Comment: Where did you find this definition of an "algebraic invariant"? If you came up with this definition by yourself, I suggest, you forget it and use the one suggested by Jyrki.